# How to use Refresh Control in UITableViewController ios7

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I am parsing an xml file and displaying it's content in a UITableView, I want to set up the pull to refresh feature. I noticed in the "attributes inspector" there is a section that says "Refreshing", I set that to Enabled. How do I actually set up the action to reload the data in the table? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can implements the **pull to refresh** feature programmatically via coding or by doing drag drops from the Storyboard. This is the example on how to do it in the easy way (using drag drops).

1. Check the `refreshing` attribute on inspector
2. Then take a look at the storyboard, there will be new view named **Refresh Control** created underneath the `TableView`. Do right click on the view then implements the `Value Changed` event.

Please see image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now I have to learn how to pull new data from the xml file.